# Error in a xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
   <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/contenedor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cabecera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#CCCCFF"
        >

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:src="@drawable/guliver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_titulo_lugar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:width="200dp" 
        android:hint="@string/titulo_lugar"
        android:inputType="text"
        />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_descripcion_lugar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:width="200dp" 
        android:hint="@string/descripcion_lugar"
        android:inputType="text"
        />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
            android:src="@drawable/camara1"
        />

        <Button android:id="@+id/guardar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textedit"
            android:text="@string/bguardar"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            />

        <Button android:id="@+id/cancelar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textedit"
            android:text="@string/bcancelar"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            />

   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When I try to run the app I have the error:
Error parsing XML: unbound prefix in the ScrollView tag.

After searching in internet I found several answers for this issue but I can't fix it. 
I also typed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

above ScrollView tag but the error persists. I also deleted the xmlns string but it isn't the solution.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Yes. After three intents of cleaning the project the error was fixed finally.

Comment: Is "android:layout_below="@+id/textedit" causing you problems? I don't see an XML element by the name of "textedit" in the XML file which you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified attribute `android:layout_height` in `ScrollView` element:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
android:layout_height = "match_parent"
```

inside `ScrolView` before or after `android:layout_width` and your problem should be gone.